# how to generate the latitudes and longitudes using google maps api with the source and destination lat longs

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I am working on google maps api,

I need to generate the latitude and longitude by using the source and destination lat/longs.

Can anybody please help out, what is the formula needs to be applied and to generate the latitudes and longitudes between the source and destination. 
Is there any formula to calculate and the lat longs from source to destination.

[Please check this image you will get an idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/275mq.png)

Comment: we must at least attempt to do some research before asking a question https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Geocoder to get the latitude and longitude of a specific location.

```
var startingPoint = 'your location';
var latitude, longitude, map, geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({'address': startingPoint}, function(results, status){
    //console latitude & longitude of your location
    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    console.log("Latitude - " + latitude);
    console.log("Longitude - " + longitude);

    if(status == 'OK'){
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()},
            zoom: 15
        }); 
    } else {
        console.log("Geocode not working - " + status);
    }
});
```

Refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) for more info about google maps api.

Comment: This is geocoding of getting the lat and longs by address. Is there any formula to generate latitudes and longitudes by providing source and destination lat longs. I have lately updated a image for the clarity.